# Strange symbol where my picture should be?

Tags: php, mysql, upload, image

I'm trying to make a database that uploads the pictures and shows them, sorta like a gallery. It uploads them but the problem is where the pictures should be it gives me this strange symbol ( sorry can't post it because I'm new :| ) and I can't tell if this means it just refuses to show them, or something went wrong. Help?

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("images") or die(mysql_error());

    $id=addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);
    $image=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dadsda WHERE id=$id");
    $image=mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
    $image=$image['image'];

    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

    print($image);
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean "mysql_fetch_assoc($image)"?  I don't think mysql_fetch_asset exists.  Also is the image column a BLOB?

Comment: it is a BLOB, and neither mysql_fetch_assoc() or echo did anything. It's returning no output, it looks like it thinks it worked, and when I check the database the stuff is there. :/

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Assuming that your `id` is always a number, you'd better cast it to an `int` or sanitize/validate it using `filter_input` or validate it with `ctype_digit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At no point in that code is the image actually output.

If `image` is a `BLOB` field in the database, you'd need to do `print $image;` after the `header()` call. If it's a filename/path, you'd need to use `readfile()` to output the contents of that file.

Also, this code is vulnerable to SQL injection. If I go to `script.php?id=1%3B+DROP+TABLE+dadsda%3B` it'll delete your database table because I just made your code execute the SQL query `SELECT * FROM dadsda WHERE id=1; DROP TABLE dadsa;`.

Comment: further to the SQL injection point above, check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Thanks for that tip, yet still even with everything everyone's said, it comes with the same results.

Comment: What does `print mysql_error(); print_r($image); exit;` output if you put it after the `$image=mysql_fetch_assoc($image);` line?

Comment: @ceejayoz nothing, sorry, forgot this part in the other script where it could be `echo "Image uploaded. <p />Your image : <p /><img src=get.php?id=$lastpicid>";`

Answer (score -2):

sometimes if the image box is empty my jpeg is not defined in your mime types on server side.. just right click on the empty image box and give me the properties...
regards..

Comment: That wouldn't matter here anyway, as the header for `Content-Type` is being defined by the PHP script.